# Hover on image not working properly

Tags: css

```
<div align="center">
<div class="se" style="width:60px;height:60px;"><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/></div>
<div class="uk" style="width:60px;height:60px;"><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/></div>
<div class="de" style="width:60px;height:60px;"><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/></div></div>
<div> i dont want this menu div to jump up and down when hover</div>
```

css file:

```
.se {margin-top:-30px;}
.se:hover {margin-top:-15px;}
.uk {margin-top:-60px; margin-left:-150px;}
.uk:hover {margin-top:-45px;}
.de{margin-top:-60px; margin-left:150px;}
.de:hover {margin-top:-45px;}
```

I just want the flags to slide down when hover. As you see in my fiddle, it's acting strange depending on with flag i hover first.

This could probably be solved in an easier way? http://jsfiddle.net/XScjm/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bartm669/XScjm/10/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="center" align="center">
    <div class="flag" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
        <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="flag" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
         <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="flag" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
        <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2013/07/10/4558947/english_flag-60x60.jpg"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div> i dont want this menu div to jump up and down when hover</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flag {margin-top:-30px; position:relative; display:inline-block;}
.flag:hover { top:15px; }
#center { height: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in the wrong way to acomplish what you want, first you can't offset the image with `margin` because that affects all arround the element. And the way you are trying to position each `<div>` with margin is unrecommended.

Try to do it this way:

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
.se, .uk, .de {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.se:hover, .uk:hover, .de:hover {
    top:15px;
}
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XScjm/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XScjm/1/):

```
.se, .uk, .de {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.se:hover img, .uk:hover img, .de:hover img {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one :-

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7N3tX/)

```
<div align="center" class="one"></div> 

.one{ height: 60px; }
```